# How to Sort Div by attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sorting, html

I have a DIV structure like this and would like to sort using following option.

1. Whats-new
2. Featured
3. price-down
4. price-up

## DIV Structure

```
<div class="product-result-panel product-list">
    <div class="show-all-products">
        <div class="ProductList product filter-enable">
            <a href="image1.jpg" data-productid="1870" data-price="29.99" data-msrp="59.99" data-isfeatured="" data-isnew="" data-gender="WOMENS" data-colour="BLUE">
        </div>
        <div class="ProductList product filter-disable">
            <a href="image2.jpg" data-productid="1871" data-price="46.99" data-msrp="59.99" data-isfeatured="10" data-isnew="" data-gender="WOMENS" data-colour="PURPLE">
        </div>

        <div class="ProductList product filter-enable">
            <a href="image3.jpg" data-productid="1872" data-price="19.99" data-msrp="59.99" data-isfeatured="" data-isnew="44" data-gender="MENS" data-colour="ORANGE">
        </div>
        <div class="ProductList product filter-enable">
            <a href="image4.jpg" data-productid="1872" data-price="59.99" data-msrp="99.99" data-isfeatured="" data-isnew="12" data-gender="MENS" data-colour="BLACK">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## SORT-Criteria

So when users select `price-low`, it should sort only `filter-enable` div's using the data-price attribute and sort by LOW-TO-HIGH, `filter-enable` is visible on the page and `filter-disable` is hidden in the DOM

## Jquery Code got so far

```
// DropDownList change event
$(document).on('change', ".sorting", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sortString = $(".sorting option:selected").val();
        SortBy(sortString);
    });

function SortBy(sortString) {
        switch(sortString) {
            case "featured":
                {
                    sortUsingNestedText($('.show-all-products'), ".ProductList:visible", "data-isfeatured");
                    break;
                }
            case "whats-new":
                {
                    sortUsingNestedText($('.show-all-products'), ".ProductList:visible", "data-isnew");
                    break;
                }
            case "price-down":
                {
                    sortUsingNestedText($('.show-all-products'), "div", "data-price");
                    break;
                }
            case "price-up":
                {
                    sortUsingNestedText($('.show-all-products'), "div", "data-price");
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

 function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
        var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function (a, b) {
            var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
            var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
            return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        parent.append(items);
    }
```

## ERROR

No Error, BUT its not doing any sorting, only first and second DIV's are getting sorted. not all of them. Is it because some of the DIV's dont have data-isfeatured, data-isnew values?

Answer (score 2):

I found the primary reason. You are useing wrong selector. Why something like "$(keySelector, a)" what it is $("data-price", "div")?
second: you get text but you need data attr and data is inside "a" not in "div" You should use something like:

```
var vA = $(a).children().attr(keySelector);
var vB = $(b).children().attr(keySelector);
```

When you use this your price-up will be working( price-down give exactly the same = the same params put inside the same function )

Comment: i think you got me there .... something is working ..BUT because i have a decimal in price... its still not sorting it perfectly...

Comment: you can use javascript parseFloat function

Comment: got it.... prices are working fine BUT then how to sort by data-isfeatured and data-isnew... same function is not working for those two

Comment: selector .ProductList:visible maybe not workig but easy use .filter-enable and will be the same right?

Comment: yes...i can use .filter-enable instead of .ProductList:visible

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert strings to floats before sorting by price.

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
            var vA = parseFloat($(a).children().data(keySelector));
            var vB = parseFloat($(b).children().data(keySelector));
            return vA - vB;
        })
```

As @Adeptus pointed out `keySelector` got to be without `data-` prefix. `

Comment: .data(keySelector) will be not working here because param is "data-price". will be work when change param to "price":)